# TS error: has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other

Tags: typescript

I am receiving a type error in my TypeScript code and could use some help understanding the issue. The error message I'm seeing is: "has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other".

Here is my code:

```js
type Data = Array<string> | Array<{ a: boolean }>

const data = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const fn = (data: Data) => {
  const isArrayOfString = Array.isArray(data)
  if (isArrayOfString) {
    const a = data.every(x => x)
    console.log(x)
  }
}
```

[Here's a link to the code on TypeScript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UCCAnDcQB4DOwGAlgHYDmAfFAD7pY64DeUcAXFAEYD23ANhDikoAX0oAocQGNupQlAAmCJKgDaAcjjqANFHWcdeqeoC6kmXOBQAZsNQAKJYg7xEAShTUm4qL6gX5YnxMbBAAeWsAZSIychR6UIA6IJCcR2U3Hz9ia3sUhnComIoPbz9y-1l5FUVlRIgANwgMEHsAD2RKNsyKvwD%20CES%20bnJ2nr8RSREgA)

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to resolve it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your check `const isArrayOfString = Array.isArray(data)` does not actually check if the contents of the array is a string and it also does not work as a way to [type narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) `data`.

`.every` refuses to work as at that point in the code, as TS can't figure out if the array is one that contains strings or one that contains an object with the key `a` set to a `boolean`.

Introduce working type guards:

```
type Data = Array<string> | Array<{ a: boolean }>

const data = ["a", "b", "c"]

const isArrayOfStrings = (data: Array<any>): data is Array<string> =>
  data.every((x) => typeof x === "string")

const fn = (data: Data) => {
  if (isArrayOfStrings(data)) {
    const a = data.every((x) => x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

There are some obvious problems with your code:

a `console.log(x)` where x is not in scope,

the `isArrayOfString` does not even check if its a string-array (for this end, `Array.every` could be used for instance),

and finally, there are 2 `data` variables in scope (which are being shadowed but nevertheless).

After fixing these the error may become much clearer. at first glance, it might be because the `every` function cannot tell which type the array members have (and thus which `every` implementation it shall use).